# apache cannot read java .class files

Tags: java, linux, apache-http-server, permissions

I have a cronjob running as root that compiles a java program and moves it into my document root where i have the ability to download it using php, trouble is apache wont even allow read access to the compiled program no matter what owner/group/permissions i give it.

`$ ll
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  3422 Jan  5 12:24 jim_HgHDJQDJQWIDIJQWIDUQIU928121818.class`

But when i check using php the results are as so ;/

`Name: jim_HgHDJQDJQWIDIJQWIDUQIU928121818 Size: - Permission: u--------- Owner/Group: /
Create time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 Access time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 Modify time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00`

I am running centos 5.8 with apache & openjdk 7 installed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you feel it is a UNIX read permission problem and NOT a configuration problem on apache level ? At apache we need to specify which all directories/Files can be read !

Comment: Odd that the creation, access, and modification times are all set to the UNIX Epoch.  Perhaps there's a bug with either the filesystem or the way Apache is handling the permissions?

Comment: The filename listed in the PHP results is different -- it's missing the `.class` suffix. Is this intentional?

Comment: This was a mistype when typing out the question.

Comment: Well i renamed jim.class to jim.html and replaced the bytecode with "test" and it still cannot be read....  "You don't have permission to access /jim.html on this server.". All my other files have exactly the same permissions and they load correctly.